# I cannot understand why "in" doesn't work correctly

Tags: pandas

sp01 is dataframe which contains S&P 500 index. And I have a dataframe,interest, which contains daily interest rate. The two data started from same date, but their size were not same. It's error.

I want to get exact same date, so tried to check every date using "in" function. But "in" function doesn't work well. This is code :

```
print(sp01.Date[0], type(sp01.Date[0]) )
->1976-06-01,  str
print(interest.DATE[0], type(interest.DATE[0]) )
->1976-06-01,  str

 print(sp01.Date[0] in interest.DATE)
->False
```

I can never understand why the result becomes False. 
Of course, first date of sp01 and interest is totally same, 
I checked it too by typing code. So, True should be come out, but False came out. I got mad!!!please Help me.

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about your data and what you want to archive? Have you tried `print(sp01.Date[0] == interest.DATE)`?

Comment: thanks for you. But I solved it. so add answer. I am happy now. great!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! the problem is that "in" function does not work for pandas series data. Those two data are pandas series, so I have to change one of them to list